# In what cases do you get the JS error: WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, websocket

I have a [js](/questions/tagged/js) script which is running on a website and a part of it sends [http](/questions/tagged/http) requests to a local server on my computer.

It seems to work, but i noticed that if I minimize the website and go to another websites, from time to time I get this error:

> WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state

What does that error means? when does is occur and how can I debug it?

Comment: The error means that the socket connection has been closed. There are lots of reasons for this to have happened; connection dropped, manually/programmatically closed/server over demand/timeout... We can't help you unless you have a specific reproducible problem, and can show us the code which causes it

Comment: Hi, the problem is that I don't know exactly how to reproduce it. I don't think it's a problem in the code because most of the time it works. especially if I keep the website which the script runs on it on.

Comment: Is it possible that a website which you minimize closes the connection with you until you maximize it again?